# Finding out how many threads make sense to create

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have some calculation task on a large amount of the data - so it can be quite easily to parallel. Next question is how many threads does it make sense to create. Of course I can measure time for different number of thread on my machine, but what if a program will be run on different machines, so I can't really make manual measurement. Is just get number of threads from `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` good enough, or there are some other ways?

Answer (score 1):

That function (`std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`) will give you the total core count, including hyperthreading.

If your program does intensive number crunching I would say using only physical cores and setting processor affinity is the best choice.

You can know the current processor topology with [hwloc](https://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/) library which works in most platforms.

You may find an comprehensible explanation (though a bit old) [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/c11-threads-affinity-and-hyperthreading/).

If there is lot of I/O then you may run two threads for processor to allow one to process data while other is waiting for input, or one extra thread without affinity so it can take processor time while others are waiting for I/O, but this is a *very* rough estimation: better measure in your machine.

If you can test in other processors, you may have different strategy for each processor.